# A "send to" search bar like the one used by Gmail

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

When you're in Gmail and want to select the of an email, you start typing the name and a suggested list appears. The selected user is added as a chip inside the search bar to then be able to move on to the next search and this iteratively.

How can I implement such a feature in android (Kotlin,XML) ?

I tried to use a TextInputlayout with a Recyclerview but I encounter the following problem:

- I don't know how to insert chips inside the TextInputEditText so I insert only some text but when I want to make a new search, this is done using all the text present in the TextInputEditText